# How do you cast a method argument to a generic without defining the generic's type in c#

Tags: c#, generics

First of all the following problem is with a Xamarin app I'm writing but I assume this happens because of C# not because of the underlying Java, if it is because of Java then please tell me so I can correct the question title

I wish to create an abstract class that I will use for the basis of all Fragment classes my project will use. So I have defined it like this:

```
public abstract class CoreFragment<T> : Fragment
```

The T in the class represents an interface that must be implemented by whichever class this Fragment attaches to, so for example my code is:

```
private T _parent;

public override void OnAttach(Activity activity){
    if (activity is T){
        _parent = activity as T;
    } else { throw new Exception("Incorrect type of parent")' }
}
```

So when I create a new fragment that should be attached only to a type that implements the interface iMainInteractions, I create it as :

```
public class MyNewFragment : CoreFragment<iMainInteractions>
```

my problem is that the code above:

```
_parent = activity as T;
```

does not compile, I even tried:

```
_parent = (T) activity;
```

because it sometimes seems to work where as 'as' doesn't and it keeps throwing a compiler error that T is not specified to be of a specific type (I assume it wants me to define something along the lines of where T : something)

if I remove it and use something like :

```
 _parent = (T) Convert.ChangeType(activity, typeof(T));
```

it will compile, it will enter the true part of the statement when the time comes but when the ChangeType tries to execute, it will throw an exception saying that activity is not implementing IConvertible

so other than creating a blank iInteraction interface as a parent of T, and having all my interaction interfaces follow this one, is there a way to make this work?

thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: Looks like the method should be defined as `public override void OnAttach(T activity){` to me. Having `OnAttach` throw an exception at run time because of the type seems... extremely broken.

Comment: Anyway, you can 'make it work' by casting to object, and then to T. `_parent = (T)(object)activity;`

Comment: @Rob I can't change the argument, it's an override method, I guess I could try creating a method `private void do_attach(T activity)` and see if it will let me call it from `OnAttach`, as for casting it, unfortunatelly activity is not a subclass of object, it is a subclass of `Java.Lang.Object`, but I will give it a shot and see if it works thank you for the answer

Comment: @Rob indeed it seems your method worked, _parent = (T)(object)activity; does indeed produce the behaviour I want even if I don't declare T as implementing something, if you wish you can add it as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `class` constraint:

```
public abstract class CoreFragment<T> : Fragment where T : class
```

The problem is the `as` operator works for reference types only, so it could safely produce a `null` in case the cast would not be valid. With `T` unconstraint, the compiler can't tell if it will be substituted with a reference or value type, and thus `as` can't operate on it.

I don't know what's your class hierarchy, but I'd consider introducing a base interface or class you could use as a type constraint. For example, if all `Activity`-like classes would have to implement a base interface such as `IActivityBase`:

```
public abstract class CoreFragment<T> : Fragment where T : IActivityBase
```

Such interface need not actually contain any members, and could serve just for the purpose of increased type safety when working with your generic classes.

Comment: yes I know , it should work like that, the thing is that T is not defined as a specific type, for example one fragment may want to communicate with an activity with an interface that responds to `move_back()` and `reset_me()` and another with an activity that responds to something completely different, I was thinking of creating a blank iInteraction fragment and declaring the class as `public abstract class CoreFragment<T> : Fragment where T : iInteraction` but I was hoping that there was a way to avoid using blank interfaces and implementing them on other fragments

Comment: @Cruces That's a way to go, sure. The `class` constraint would suffice—I doubt your 'activity' may be an `int` or `decimal` or whatever value type. However, I'd strongly recommend introducing a common interface, although maybe memberless, for the sake of added type safety.

Comment: @OndrejTucny is right, T should be constrained to a marker interface for the very least.

Comment: I guess it's all that I can do, it seems weird because in Java I could do what I am mentioning, but it seems I have to adapt to c#'s restrictions, thanks for the replies

Comment: @Cruces It's not really a restriction, it's rather a flexibility of the language and CLR. In fact, Java **does not** allow primitive generic type arguments, but C# **does** allow them. And this is exactly the case: in order for `as` to work, the argument *must* be a reference type, avoiding primitive types. There's **nothing wrong at all** with the `class` constraint (at least), avoiding primitive data types which is what you need, for your case.